# Get key values from inner json object

Tags: java, json

I have a json object like below

```
String jsonStr ="{\"m\":{\"p\":{\"0\":{\"ms\":{\"s\":1}}}}}";
```

From this I want to get the value of key s

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

System.out.println(object.get("m"));

JSONObject mObj  = (JSONObject) object.get("m");
JSONObject pObj  = (JSONObject) mObj.get("p");
JSONObject oObj  = (JSONObject) pObj.get("0");
JSONObject sObj  = (JSONObject) oObj.get("ms");
System.out.println(sObj.get("s"));
```

Instead of using the above logic is there any ways to easily get the value of key s

Comment: What about creating an object that represent the json and you will have one line of code to reach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an object that represents the JSON would be a much cleaner approach. However, for dynamic keys recursion could be used.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

String jsonStr = "{\"m\":{\"p\":{\"0\":{\"ms\":{\"s\":1}}}}}";
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Map data = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, Map.class);
Object value = obj.get(data, "s");
System.out.println(value); //1.0

//Input JSON as Map & key to search on
public Object get(Map data, String key) {
    System.out.println(data);
    if (!data.containsKey(key)) {
        for (Object v : data.values()) {
            return get((Map) v, key);
        }
    }
    return data.get(key);
}
```

Comment: but what is this obj ? Object value = obj.get(data, "s");

Comment: obj is the object of the class where the above method is implemented.